# Laggy css :hover transitions on newest version of Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am developing a pretty simple website. On the computer on which I work, I was using chromium for quite a while now, and have not updated it, so it stayed at version 67. Now, I have moved to the newest version of Chrome (79) and I became quite frustrated seeing, that all of a sudden, without me changing any code, the CSS transitions pretty much do not work anymore. It's as if it was very laggy. ( sometimes it registers hover on element after a very long delay, sometimes not, when it does it usually does not register the end of the hover ... ). Yet, I once again checked on old version of chromium, I even checked on IE too, and it works perfectly on those browser.

Here's the html of the sidebar on which the elements I talk about are located ( it's not only on the sidebar, but I think it's the best example ):

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <h1 class="special-fx-opacity invisible">CONSTRUCTION REALIZATIONS</h1>
    <div class="sidebar-el">
        <h2 onclick="location.href = '[censored]';" class="special-fx-opacity invisible">Novus&Mediucs Clinic, Oslo</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-sep special-fx-opacity invisible"></div>
    <div class="sidebar-el">
        <h2 class="special-fx-opacity invisible">House, Hvistenveien</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-sep special-fx-opacity invisible"></div>
    <div class="sidebar-el">
        <h2 class="special-fx-opacity invisible">Krewetka Cinema, Gdańsk</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-sep special-fx-opacity invisible"></div>
    <div class="sidebar-el">
        <h2 class="special-fx-opacity invisible">Houses in Mateblewo, Gdańsk</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-sep special-fx-opacity invisible"></div>
    <div class="sidebar-el">
        <h2 class="special-fx-opacity invisible">House, Sweden</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-sep special-fx-opacity invisible"></div>
    <button class=" button special-fx-opacity invisible">See all</button>

    <div id="social-media">
        <a href="[link censored]" target="_blank"><img src="../../imgs/fb-transparent-icon.png" alt="" class="social-media-icon special-fx-opacity invisible"></a>
        <a href="[link censored]" target="_blank"><img src="../../imgs/yt-logo-transparent.png" alt="" class="social-media-icon special-fx-opacity invisible"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here are the styles for the elements which are supposed to change color on hover ( added `z-index`  to try fix the problem, but it didn't help nothing):

```
.sidebar-el h2{
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    color: #808080;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 200;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    z-index: 3;

}

.sidebar-el h2:hover{
    color: #cd1120;
}
```

along with this, my page has some simple jQuery which is checking the scroll offset, so when an element appears on the screen, it slowly appears with an animation ( somehow this animation works perfect... ), along with making a sidebar sometimes fixed and sometimes not, dependent on offset.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#photo-gallery-container').offset().top,
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log((hT-wH) , wS);

    $('.special-fx-opacity').each(function(i,obj){
        if(wS > ($(obj).offset().top - wH)){
            $(obj).addClass('visible')
            $(obj).removeClass('invisible')
        }
    });
    if (wS > 100){
        $('#sidebar-container').addClass('visible')
        $('#sidebar-container').removeClass('invisible')
    }
    if (wS > wH){
        $('#sidebar-container').addClass('sidebar-container-fixed')
        $('#sidebar-container').removeClass('sidebar-container-stopped-top')
    }
    else{
        $('#sidebar-container').addClass('sidebar-container-stopped-top')
        $('#sidebar-container').removeClass('sidebar-container-fixed')
    }
    if (wS > (hT-wH) ){
        $('#sidebar-container').addClass('sidebar-container-stopped-bottom')
        $('#sidebar-container').removeClass('sidebar-container-fixed')
    }
   //if (wS > (hT- wH) && )
});
```

I do not know how this JS could affect the whole thing, especially that the whole thing runs just perfect on every other browser ( or even on older versions of chrome ), but I suspect it might actually be correlated, because on my index.html, where there is no sidebar and no scroll offset tracking, every :hover transition works nice even on up-to-date Chrome.

Here's Chrome 79:
[image: damn thing doesn't work]

and here's Chrome 67:
[image: smooth as butter]

I'm totally lost by now, any help appreciated, I've got no errors in console by the way...

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/16855096?hl=en

Comment: @Gerard this has nothing to do with debugging really, neither am i using Chrome canary. What does this thread even have to do with the issue? The problem is what i displayed on the gifs, the CSS animation itself is not working on latest Chrome versions.

Comment: i have a feeling this is going to be one of those tumbleweed questions... Any tips appreciated, maybe not even answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Turns out it is a kind of paranormal issue coming from the deeply philosophical inner workings of CSS...

I made a slideshow script (you can actually see it on the gifs), and it changes the width of the photos displayed, thus changing a layout style, which causes the lag. This issue is very nicely described in an [excellent article](https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108) i read recently browsing dev blogs, so it actually came to mind when i started checking if my JS was at fault. ( huge thanks to the author, José Rosário, this is actually very little known, i have never seen this anywhere, and as i just found out, it definetely is practical )

I did all the tests and it indeed turns out that while the animation, transition of the `width` style is taking place on the ***Layout*** rendering phase, the rendering of the `box-shadow`, `color`, and other styles in the ***Painting*** phase are delayed. These layout changes occured pretty much all the time, every 1.5  seconds, and the animation took about 0.8 seconds.

Still, it's a very nice looking effect, so i'm going to have to rewrite the whole thing using the super fancy *cutting-edge* ***Composite*** styles, which are faster and will not delay the style changes rendered in the ***Painting*** phase, aswell as use truly *awe-inspiring* ***GPU-rendering*** technology, as described in the article if time allows ( deploying the website today ).

Once again, shoutout to the author of that article, you should definetely read it if you deal with advanced front-end. Nobody ever mentioned this to me before, i stumbled upon the article by chance a while ago...
[image: The rendering order]
*The order of style rendering in web browsers*

**EDIT:** Instead of making a whole new thing, i made something almost identical very quickly using [glide.js](https://glidejs.com/), which uses all the fancy tricks described above

**EDIT#2:** (just to not mislead anybody)  seeing the slideshow stuttering i'm not entirely sure glide.js uses ALL the tricks from the article, namely i don't think the animation is GPU rendered, it looks a litte bit laggy sometimes, but it's very minimal

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:-

```
.sidebar-el>h2:hover{
color: #cd1120;
}
```

Or you can directly use:-

```
h2:hover{
color:#cd1120;
}
```

This have help me but if it doesn't work for you then you can also use jQuery for hover effect, just like:-

```
$("h2").hover(function(){
$(this).css("color", "#cd1120");
}, function(){
$(this).css("color", "#808080");
}
);
```

Comment: The css style did not change anything, as i expected, because as far as i am aware, practically speaking, it's the same thing if you use ">" or space. Either way i want to avoid JS and jQuery as much as possible, so i will wait till some better answer comes about, otherwise i guess i'll just use jQuery animate instead of a bare-bones style change like this. Thanks for the help anyway though.